# Presto error while querying hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

1. Querying `select * from table_name limit 10;` in Hive returns correct data. But querying same table through presto connection returns below error :

> Presto query has failed. cannot find field  from
>   [0:error_error_error_error_error_error_error,
>   1:cannot_determine_schema, 2:check, 3:schema, 4:url, 5:and, 6:literal]

2. Querying `select count(*) from table_name;` in Hive returns correct data. But querying the same table through presto connection returns below error :

> Presto query has failed. HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

I have gone through this [link1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/uPApa6ih2B0) and [link2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/CpEDvLiUSX0) already but it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by correcting avro schema.

Comment: What was the issue in your schema since its giving correct data in the hive? I am facing the similar issue where my queries are running in the hive but not in presto